# Inserting additional same no of rows but with negative value in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

[Actually I have a million records but I have taken an example in picture.

Initial table contains 3 records but the result I need is same 3 rows + same number of rows (same data) but with negative values....So resulted table has 6 records in pic

The question is initially I have million of records with positive values

But the resulted table I need is both previous data and insert same copy of data with negative values… If I have 100 records...The resulted table contains 200 records (100 positive and 100 negative records)

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxyoF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` as follows:

```
insert into your_Table
select a, -B, -c from your_table
```

Comment: If there are millions of records, will this statement perform well?

Comment: Why not? just try it once. anyway, It will be your one time activity, as far as I can assume.

Comment: You can consider accepting the answer if it worked for you. :)